# cantools.database get the sending node of a message

Tags: python, can-bus

I have a program where I need to know the CAN-node of a message, I get from a DBC. I read the DBC like this:

```
db_input = cantools.db.load_file(dbc_path,database_format='dbc',encoding=None,frame_id_mask=None,strict=True,cache_dir=None)
```

I get a specific message like this:

```
print(db_input.messages[0])
```

and output is:

```
message('HOURS', 0x18fee59e, True, 8, None)
```

However in the DBC the message has the according CAN-node:

```
BO_ 2566841758 HOURS: 8 Sensor3
```

DBC syntax is this:

```
BO_ <CAN-ID> <MessageName>: <MessageLength> <SendingNode>
```

Is it possible to get something like this?:

```
 message('HOURS', 0x18fee59e, True, 8, Sensor3)
```

PS. I have looked at the specific node and the output is:

```
node('Sensor3', None)
```

maybe the None is wrongly taken as the node input, but I couldn´t find were the node is inputted in the source-code of the cantools.database library
https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/cantools/database.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/cantools/database/can/message.html) you should be able to get the sender(s) with `.senders`:

```
print(db_input.messages[0].senders)
```

What you're printing is only the representation of the message (see `__repr__` in my link). The message has more properties (`_senders` among others)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but you need to use db_input.messages[0].senders inset of db_input.messages[0].senders(), because the list object is not callable

Comment: Oh you right! I missed the `@property`. Fixing it right away... Thanks for pointing it out!